# LSTM model gives good training but poor test results, however can't see overfitting

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

Here is how my data are :

I have 500 recordings (arbitrary split into training, validation and test set). Each recording contains a certain number of rows, each one corresponding to a EEG segment of 1s. In other words, the length of each recording is equal to the length of an EEG signal (in s). Each rows contains 22 channels * 22 temporal/frequential features =484 features + the output label (0 or 1).

So I want to perform binary classification.

As suggested by many papers (look at [this good paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09776)), for each recording, I create sequences of length `look_back` so that each label is predicted taking into account the features of the segments "around". Here is the code :

```
def create_dataset(feat,targ, look_back=1):
   semi_window=math.floor(look_back/2)
   dataX, dataY = [], []
   for i in range(semi_window,len(targ)-semi_window):
       a = feat[i-semi_window:(i+semi_window+1), :]
       dataX.append(a)
       dataY.append(targ[i])
   return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

This function returns a 3-D array of size `(samples, look_back=time_steps, features=484)`.

To deal with imbalanced classes, I tested both the `make_imbalance` function to drop instances to keep the same number of instances of each class and the `class_weight` parameter that takes the imbalance into account in the loss function.

So, I used a LSTM model and used EarlyStopping callback parameter to stop once validation accuracy does not increase by a given tolerance.

Here is my full model :

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [earlystop]
np.random.seed(10)
set_random_seed(30)
rn.seed(50)
# plutôt que faire imbalance qui supprime plic ploc les données, on préfère introduire class_weight et ne pas shuffler les données (ben en fait si..)...
weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(trainY),trainY)
print (weights)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2]), recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))


model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print (model.summary())
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(validX, validY), epochs=100, batch_size=32, class_weight=weights, verbose=1 , callbacks=callbacks_list, shuffle=True)  

train_score = model.evaluate(trainX, trainY, batch_size=2048)
print(train_score)
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
print(confusion_matrix(trainY, trainPredict.round()))                      

valid_score = model.evaluate(validX, validY, batch_size=2048)
print(valid_score)
validPredict = model.predict(validX)
print(confusion_matrix(validY, validPredict.round()))

test_score = model.evaluate(testX, testY, batch_size=2048)
print(test_score)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
print(confusion_matrix(testY, testPredict.round()))
```

and I get this kind of results :

[image]

The training confusion matrix is outstanding but the validation and test matrices are poor...

I guess it's not overfitting, as my model is of very little size (one layer,...). Moreover, I guess the model is appropriated because it manages to discriminate very well the data on the (huge) training set...

So, what's wrong ?

NB: I do say that I have the same kind of problem with a classical Keras feed forward neural network

EDIT : Here is what I get when I plot the learning curves :

[image]
 What you can see is that the training accuracy remains really high while the validation accuracy (actually orange curves should be for "validation") remains really low...

EDIT: I tried to use XGBoost and SVM classifiers but I can't manage to get results (still quite the same behaviour)

EDIT : I tried to shuffle the data and see. I get very good results BUT it's kind of mirage... Indeed, I have data coming from the same recordings (not identically the same but very close) in both training and validation sets... kind of cheating. When I present a totally new recording to the model, it crashes down... So, I have not already found a solution

Comment: @abdulqayyum Maybe, but where does it come from ?? Certainly not because my model is too deep...

Comment: Change batch_size to 16 instead of 32. And add few more layers. Few iterations in number of layers, dataset preprocessing and batch size will give you better insight. (my first comment got deleted accidentally)

Comment: I already try to tune batch_size, it does not change @abdulqayyum

Comment: @abdulqayyum increasing the number of layers did not change anything

Comment: it's not because there is only one layer that it does not overfit. The split may be the cause of the poor results. To prevent this, you really need to do a KFold (or statified KFold). If the Datasets are too different, it will perform badly no matter what you do. You should also try to see the distribution of feature and maybe(just maybe) try to Normalize/Standarize them

Comment: @Alexis Actually, I already standardised the data. By KFold, you mean cross validation ?

Comment: yes but in a randomize way, don't arbitrary split, put all the datas together and then do cross val with StratifiedKFold to make sure that those bad results are not comming from a too brutal partition of your set

Comment: Would it be possible for you to plot the train/validation loss curves?

Comment: @rvinas I updated, could you please have a look at how the curves behave ?

Comment: Have you tried to use validation_split? That way it takes random samples from the data set. model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_split=0.1) (10%)

Comment: @CAta.RAy Due to the structure of my data, I can't blindly randomly choose the split but I did make some randomization, though